# Why the php show no error but it cant show what I want?

Tags: php, html

Why the php show no error but it cant show what I want?
What I want is to search the position from database and echo it out.

```
<?php
    require ('sql_connect.php');

    $id= $_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM student WHERE student_id ='$id' ");
    $q = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    $position = $q['name'];
    echo ($position);
?>
```

HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form onsubmit="return formValidator()" action="insert2.php" method="post">
    <p>

        Student Id :<?php echo $position; ?>

    </p>
    <p> 
            Password :<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value='1' 
            onchange="document.getElementById('password').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"/>
    </p>
    <p>

        Name :<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

    </p>

    <p>
            Email :<input type="text" name="email" id="email" name="email"/> 
    </p>
    <p>
            Contact Number :<input type="text" id="contactnumber" name="contactnumber"/> 
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you repeat your question ?

Comment: What if, instead of inflating your text and repeating it, you actually said more about your problem?

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); at top of your php file, to see the errors if that's not configured in your php.ini file. Also check if mysql connection is created in sql_connect.php.

Comment: can you show me how ？ idont get it

Comment: `$position = $q["name"]` feels weird too. Why would the position be stored in the column named "name"

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with `name=id` in your code.

Than, you don´t care about `SQL injection` (you expected id (number), so `... WHERE student_id = " . (int)$id . " ...`), student name is in `$position` variable... But the main problem is, that there is no name=id element, so `$_REQUEST['id']` (aka `$_POST['id']`) doesn't exist.

Comment: That's only if the request comes from that HTML page when it might come from another form.

Comment: Another form? I don´t using REQUEST var, but I suppose it is `$_POST + $_GET  + $_COOKIE`. Sure, he can store that in COOKIE, but he´s making a search form (to search a student), so I expect he want get ID from this form.

Comment: id could be set from a form which send you to this page/form which grabs the id to display inside a form but that form can be sent to another page. Also here id could have come from a link. as it www.url.com/addStudent.php?id=foo. You seem to assume there is only one form and that that form is submitted to that page too. I hope it's not the case as it's poor design.

Comment: You're right! But here, only user3714966 know what he want and what he have.

Comment: Yep he needs to add more information as currently it makes it impossible to answer his question with accuracy :)

Comment: what i want is to get the name from the php and then pass it to html form to display it as student ID